# Applying form validation of select menu similar to html5 required attribute of <input>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, client-side-validation

I'm trying to make everything in my form required, including the select menus. w3schools says that no major browsers support the `required` attribute on `<select>` tags..

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Is there really no way to provide client side validation on select menus the same way as input text fields? I have a [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Do5hLrfahx6akY7uIEL2?p=preview) here, where if you click check with everything blank, the warning appears under the the first input, even though there is a select menu above it.

if it were working the "this field is required" message would appear under the select menu since it is the first invalid form item. Additionally if you fill out all input fields no message appears anywhere. The code is in angular and spans  5 files, so view it on the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Do5hLrfahx6akY7uIEL2?p=preview) .

If you know any way to apply the same validation to select menus, or have confirmation this is impossible, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: required absolutely works in all major browsers & with angular you can easily check the `form.valid` property on submit which will tell you if it's valid or not. I wouldn't ever listen to w3schools unless you know what you are doing and just need a function reference.

Comment: what are you doing with the form when it is submitted? If it's calling a PHP file you could do the validation in there instead and redirect if there's an error.

Comment: @ShanRobertson is that not only when used with an `<input>` tag with html5? (genuine question)

Comment: @SO that would be server side validation, which already exists. it's calling a PHP AJAX file

Comment: @SO correct, you have to have a valid html5 document.

Comment: @J-Dizzle my bad, skipped over the 'client side' requirement when reading...

Comment: @ShanRobertson yeah, w3fools i typically avoid. how do I check the form.valid property, and then cause the same alert that happens for <input> items?

Comment: the alerts come up automatically. In your controller, watch the form's submit event. the first argument will be the form data so `function(form){if(form.valid){//form submit is valid}}`

Comment: Unrelated but the CSS effect for your input label text in your example is GREAT!

Comment: @ShanRobertson so I could have a ng-submit that calls a function like you just commented, but within that if statement is exactly what I'm looking for -- the "alert" that is behind the scenes that is apparently only applied to `<input>`, I could figure it out if I knew how that alert happened

Comment: @J-Dizzle 1st recommendation: do not ever use w3schools. The content of this website is often outdated (I read it was good "back in the days"). read more http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @J-Dizzle use Mozilla's website instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML or directly the relevant version of the HTML5 specification http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3schools is incorrect as usual. Useful references like [MDN on `select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) tell that `required` is supported by modern versions of all major browsers; the main problem with support is lack of support in IE 9 and older.

However, you need to note the definition of the attribute: it means that the control satisfies the constraint if and only if its value is nonempty. Since the first option is selected by default (unless you make another option initially selected using the `selected` attribute), you need to make its value empty. Example:

```css
:invalid { outline: solid red }
```

```html
<form>
<select name=fruit required>
  <option value="">Please select a fruit
  <option>apple
  <option>orange
</select>
<input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

If you need to cover IE 9 and older, too, just add simple JavaScript code that checks that `value` property of the `select` element is not empty when the form is to be submitted (or whenever you are checking the form data in the browser).

Comment: added `...> <option value=""></option> </select>` to select.html in my plunkr, and didn't conflict with any CSS. Amazingly quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in HTML 5 alerts aren't coming up because technically you already have an option selected.  Angular's `select` directive creates and defaults to a blank option if the `ng-model` attribute in the element doesn't refer to a specific options value.

Inspect your select element and you'll see

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

You could have your `ng-model` attribute refer to a valid options value and then hide the automatically generated blank value option, but then, you would always have a value pre-selected and your animation effects for select elements would be lost.  See example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ykB0QRoRyzJxywcWdHhJ?p=preview).

Your only other option is to create your own validation and have a div underneath each select element that either shows or hides based on if a valid value is selected.